# print 1,1 2,1 2 3,1 2 3 4 ...... through c#

Tags: c#, .net

print 1,1 2,1 2 3,1 2 3 4 ...... through c#

Comment: We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, it looks like lazy student's homework

Comment: OK, so we *will* do your homework for you.

Comment: If you post the code that you have attempted so far, or at list outline how you think it could be solved, you will get some good guidance based on that.

Comment: @Anthony for every 10 people who says we won't, there's at least one who say we will. It only takes one.

Comment: @Matthew - crappy side effect of points driven rep :s

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested loop. The outer counts up the limit and prints the comma, the inner loop prints the space separated consecutive numbers. But you should be able to come up with such a solution yourself.

Here is once fancy but unreadable one:

```
String.Join(",",
    Enumerable.Range(1,10)
    .Select(i=> String.Join(" ",
        Enumerable.Range(1,i)
        .Select(j=>j.ToString()))))
```

Comment: Don't even need that much. A single loop, a `StringBuilder` and print as you go. Done.

Comment: Nice idea. But it may be shorter, but conceptually harder. And the OP looks like a beginner.

Comment: If we're answering homework, we may as well go out of our way to teach and tip off professors too while we're at it.

Answer (score 3):

Use nested loops. Use the outside to count how many numbers you're going to count this pass and then use the inner loop to actually count through the numbers each time:

```
for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++)
{
    for(int a=1; a <= i; a++)
    {
        Console.Write(a + " ");
    }

    Console.Write(", ");
}
```

P.S. - If this is a homework question rather than sheer curiosity (or a simplified version of a larger problem) please be sure to tag it as such. The answers will give much more explanation rather than simply giving you code.

Comment: `a.ToString() + " "`. `a` won't be converting implicitly in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The naive solution uses nested loops. You can do it without nested loops:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
int n = 1;
while (true) {
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} ", n));
    Console.Write("{0}, ", sb.ToString().TrimEnd());
    n++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very naive and quick solution

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
      Console.Write(j.ToString()+" ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < maxNumber; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < i+1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
        Console.Write(',');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(j.ToString());
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was fun trying to achieve this completely in LINQ/method chains, but I only could do it halfway. Any suggestions, on how to get rid of the recursive method?

```
string GetNumberString(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return "1";
    else
        return GetNumberString(n-1)+" "+n;
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1,10).
          Select(n => GetNumberString(n)).Aggregate((a, b) => a+", "+b));       
}
```