# how to print 1,2 2,3 3 3,4 4 4 4... through c#

Tags: c#, .net

how to print 1,2 2,3 3 3,4 4 4 4... through c#

Comment: Adapting the answers from your previous question shouldn't be that hard. You can just print the outer loop variable instead of the inner one.

Comment: What? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432973/print-1-1-2-1-2-3-1-2-3-4-through-c

Comment: I don't know, what statements did your teacher cover today?

Comment: This smells like a class assignment

Comment: He is probably now getting job and post this question with mobile phone... )

Comment: He may be having interview in about 10 min. So posted to get some idea about printing different patterns.

Comment: Make use of your brain too :) its very simple.. make use of for or Console.writeline("...")

Answer (score 44):

```
Console.WriteLine("1,2 2,3 3 3,4 4 4 4...");
```

Comment: +1 for understanding and answering the question correctly

Comment: No need to smile. It perfectly answers the authors question and should be marked as such.

Comment: i want to print 1,2 2,3 3 3 in different lines

Comment: Console.WriteLine("1,");Console.WriteLine("2 2,") etc

Comment: please dont ans if u dont understand the ques this not a joke

Comment: Then, your question is a joke :P

Comment: @Akki0007: They were just kidding before this question it's closed. This is not a "we-do-your-homework" site... you can ask for specific problem blocking you during the resolution of an assignment, not for a complete solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var to = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count <= i; count++)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat("{0} ", i);
            }
            if (i != to)
            {
                builder.Append(String.Format(","));
            }
        }

        builder.Append("...");
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

[image]

```
 var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var to = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count <= i; count++)
            {
                builder.AppendFormat("{0} ", i);
            }
            if (i != to)
            {
                builder.Append(String.Format("\n"));
            }
        }

        builder.Append("...");
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't print the dots and stopped at 10 instead of 4. Please update your answer and I won't downvote you :p

Comment: ok!Will post exactly  :)

Comment: actually i want print 1 in first line 2 2 in second line 3 3 3 in third line and so on

Comment: your line `for (int count = 0; count <= i; count++)` should read `for (int count = 1; count <= i; count++)` as you're printing each number one too many times  :o)

Comment: hey Akki0007.  Andrew is give you solution to print one time

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{

    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        if (k > 1) Console.Write(" ");
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    Console.Write(",");
}
```

or line breaks instead of commas:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{

    for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        if (k > 1) Console.Write(" ");
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```